# PHP getting cell id/tower of a mobile

Tags: php, web-applications

How can we get the information of the mobile using PHP information like cell id,cell tower and access points.Does the mobile sends headers or data to the web server when he request a page?How could we get those information if they are sending data every time they request a page?Do you have Any web(server/client) scripting language to suggest in order get those data.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same thing [you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548214/is-it-possible-to-access-the-nmea-information-of-the-devices-using-php)? The answer is still: Unless the mobile sends this info voluntarily or you're the network operator, there's no way to get it. I don't know of any mobiles that *do* send it voluntarily by default.

Comment: Do you want one that reads SMS or just Phonebook?

Comment: Yes that is the same thing I asked yesterday the NMEA but now i think that every mobile has a cell id in which they send its cell id to a cell tower if I can get the cell tower location maybe I can use that information they are sending.Each time you walk or your location is change there is a data being sent to some tower(s) or server.I'm still on a research for this.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @webarto Is it a web application you are talking? I'm all about location or if you can share that sms/phonebook I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the browser specifically sends the information, there is no way you can get at it. You'd need a mobile app to post that data to you (maybe as headers)